# Add TLS configuration for SIP account in PJSIP

Tags: c, linux, voip, tls1.2, pjsip

Hi i am creating a VOIP application in Linux using PJSIP, my app will work as a sip client and register to a sip server using asterisk. I have successfully registered SIP account with TCP and UDP but when i change to TLS, my app can not register account with error: Connection refused from SIP server. My code is as below:

```
    /* Add TLS transport. */

    pjsua_transport_id cfg_transport_id[24];
    pjsua_transport_config cfg_transport[24];

    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg_transport[0]);
    cfg_transport[i].port = ar_config[0].sip_port;
    pjsip_tls_setting tls;
    pjsip_tls_setting_default (&tls);
    char *cert_file = "/home/linphone/voip_project/test_TLS/CA_1/MyCertificate.crt";
    char *key = "/home/linphone/voip_project/test_TLS/CA_1/MyKey.key";
    tls.cert_file.ptr = cert_file;
    tls.privkey_file.ptr = key;

    tls.method = 31;
    tls.proto = 3;
    cfg_transport[i].tls_setting = tls;
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, &cfg_transport[i], &cfg_transport_id[i]);

    /* Register SIP account 0 */
    pjsua_acc_config cfg;
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);
    char id[100];
    char reg_uri[100];
    sprintf(id,"sip:%s@%s", ar_config[0].username, ar_config[0].domain);
    cfg.id = pj_str(id);
    cfg.transport_id = cfg_transport_id[i];

    sprintf(reg_uri, "sip:%s", ar_config[0].domain);
    cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(reg_uri);
    cfg.cred_count = 1;
    cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str((char *)"*");
    cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str((char *)"digest");
    cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(ar_config[i].username);
    cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(ar_config[0].secret);
    printf ("id : %s, reg_uri : %s, secret : %s \n",cfg.id.ptr,cfg.reg_uri.ptr,cfg.cred_info[0].data.ptr);
    status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &ar_config[i].acc_id);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account 0", status);
```

I generated certificate and private key follow this link: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/create-a-self-signed-tls-certificate/
I think i am missing something when add certificate and private key in PJSIP but not sure what am i missing.

Comment: do you have any log from the server? Also, you can check tcpdump of the TLS port and see if your server receives anything from your TLS port on the server as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check if **TLS_SIP (5161)** or **TLS_PJSIP (5061)** and verify if the port is open with `netcat`:

```bash
nc -vz -w2 server.example.com 5061
nc -vz -w2 server.example.com 5161
```

Usually older PBX are SIP and newer are PjSIP. Then test the output of certificate TLS connexion:

```bash
openssl s_client -connect server.example.com:5061
```

You have also to verify if is necessary the certificate in bundle pem form (which integrate the CA root / intermediate cert)